# Jetty 11 distribution missing

Tags: jetty, jetty-11

What is the official way to setup a Jetty 11 standalone instance?

We have migrated our web application to Java 17. For development we are using the latest jetty 11.0.15 maven plugin. Now we need a Jetty 11.0.15 standalone instance on Debian 11 but there is no Debian package for Jetty 11. Neither is there a stable jetty-distribution for Jetty 11 under https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/

Comment: There is no jetty-distribution any more - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68637209/775715